# CSS blocks is not working on Gmail App Mobile

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor

I`m having this issue when I am viewing the email using Gmail App (Mobile):

- The table columns are stacking on mobile on all email clients except the Gmail App

I noticed that the styles are not working on google, but if i put the CSS using inline (Ex. style="background-color:red") it works.

I saw a lot of articles saying that the  does not works on gmail, but another saying that works if you put it inside the  tag.

Main Layout:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>
        <!-- Used for storing title of the email -->
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("Subject")
    </title>

    <!-- The VisitorIdentification control ensures that people viewing this page with a traditional web browser will be classified as humans not bots. This control is not required if people only view messages using Email clients -->
    @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()

    @if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
    {
        <link href="~/Assets/5-Components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
            }

            .wrapper > tbody > tr > td {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            @@media only screen and (max-width:720px) {
                .wrapper {
                    width: 90% !important;
                    margin: auto;
                }

                .templateColumnContainer {
                    display: block !important;
                    /* padding: 0 !important; */
                    width: 100% !important;
                }

                .marginBtm {
                    margin-bottom: 0px;
                }

                .footerLeft {
                    border-right: 5px #c2c2c2 solid;
                    border-bottom: 0px #c2c2c2 solid !important;
                }

                .footerRight {
                    border-left: 5px #c2c2c2 solid;
                    border-top: 0px #c2c2c2 solid !important;
                }
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body style="min-height: 97vh; background-color:#c2c2c2; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box" class="@((Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing) ? "edit-mode" : string.Empty)">
    <div style="min-height: 97vh; margin:0; padding-top: 16px; background-color:#c2c2c2; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box">
    

        <center>
            @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("mail-body")
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Component Placeholder:

```
@model XX.Project.EXM.Models.ColumnComponent

<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer marginBtm" style="background-color: @Model.BackgroundColor; border: 5px #c2c2c2 solid; Padding: @Model.getFormattedPaddingDistance(); color:@Model.TextColor;">
                @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("mail-left-double-column")
            </td>
            <td width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer" style="background-color: @Model.BackgroundColor; border: 5px #c2c2c2 solid; Padding: @Model.getFormattedPaddingDistance(); color:@Model.TextColor;">
                @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("mail-right-double-column")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Email clients are all different and there is no standard. It's the wild west out there Fernando. GMail App on mobile is probably removing the `<style>` element from your `<head>` section. When it comes to emails, you're always safer to use inline styles.

Comment: If you'd like to try out a well tested solution for emails, check out [Cerberus](https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/). Check out their documentation and you'll see all sorts of tips on CSS for emails.

Answer (score 0):

When GMail encounters an error in your CSS, it will remove the entire `<style>` block from the head.

You have 2 `@` symbols in front of your media query.

```
@@media only screen and (max-width:720px) {
```

Comment: The @ is a reserved character in Razor, thats why i am using @@

Comment: I see. What does the final output look like?

Comment: The page is not respecting the styles, still showing one column next to the other, but if i put the style direct on td, it works. I can not do that, because i want it to be dynamic, if it is mobile, put one column on top of the other one.